# bool error (trying a game tutorial)

Tags: ios, swift

hello I am new to coding and stack overflow and lately have been practicing with Swift language. following a tutorial for a tic-tac-toe game I have come across an issue with my boolean statement. I have gotten an error with this code:

```
 userMessage.hidden = true
 if (!plays[sender.tag] &&!aiDeciding && !done != nil) {
     setImageForSpot(sender.tag, player:1)
 }
 checkForWin()
 aiTurn()
```

that is after me playing around a bit but the original issue that arose was from entering the following exactly from following the tutorial

```
@IBAction func UIButtonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
     userMessage.hidden = true
     if !plays[sender.tag] && !aiDeciding && !done {
        setImageForSpot(sender.tag, player:1)
     }
}
```

I am using Xcode 6 and the tutorial is using the beta before release idk if that has some code changes that I may be finding my issue or something on my end.
I am new to this language and overall coding with iOS so I'll like a new explanation if possible lol.

Comment: How is `done` declared? Is it type `Bool?` ?  How about `aiDeciding` as well?

Comment: Is this tutorial online?  Can you provide a link?

Comment: You need to include way more info in your question... For example what is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LkYpoRj-7hA 
this is the tutorial I'm using
"optional type '$19' cannot be used for the boolean test for '!=nil' instead" for the first one
 and the error i get is '!=' is not a prefix unary operator for the second

Comment: suppose to be a bool statement for when user clicks a button. and the !aiDeciding is for what the ai does if its a X or O then enter

Answer (score 0):

The way that xCode tries to fix it will not work.. I played around with it for a while and found the solution...

```
        @IBAction func UIButtonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
            ticTacLabel.hidden = true
            if plays[sender.tag] == nil && !aiDeciding && !done {
                  setImageForSpot(sender.tag, player:1)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
@IBAction func UIButtonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
    userMessage.hidden = true
    if plays[sender.tag] == nil && !aiDeciding && !done {
        setImageForSpot(sender.tag, player:1)
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain more your answer please ?