# How to fix this If statement?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, if-statement

I'm working on a Tic Tac Toe game and am following an Tnternet tutorial, but while I'm reproducing the code this error appear in my If statement:

**This is the error message:**

> Binary operator '&&' cannot be applied to two Bool operands

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {

    if !plays[sender.tag] != nil && !aiDecided != nil && !done != nil {

       setImageSpot(sender.tag, player: 1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the values you're testing are Booleans, remove the comparison with nil.

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {

    // this checks if all these Boolean values are false  
    if let tag = plays[sender.tag] where !tag && !aiDecided && !done {

       setImageSpot(sender.tag, player: 1)

    }

}
```

UPDATE: you said in comments that your dictionary is actually returning integers instead of boolean values.

`var plays = Dictionary<Int,Int>()` means that the first value you check in this IF statement is not a Bool but an Int, so the current code can't work indeed.

In this case, and assuming this is on purpose, here's an example that works *but you shouldn't actually use numbers as booleans values, use Bool types instead*:

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {

    // this checks if all Boolean values are false
    // this is also assuming that 0 from "plays" means false and 1 means true
    if let tag = plays[sender.tag] where tag != 0 && !aiDecided && !done {

        setImageSpot(sender.tag, player: 1)

    }

}
```

Comment: the first one is a dictionary and i did that in the first time and this is Xcode message: Optional type 'Bool' cannot be used as a boolean; test for '!= nil' instead

Comment: Updated my answer. See also Qbyte's answer in case your other values are Optionals too.

Comment: these are my variable:  var plays = Dictionary<Int,Int>()
    var aiDecided = false
    var done = false

Comment: any code inside the function didn't work i check it with a println() is there anyway to make it run...

Answer (score 0):

**i found the solution for the question in this link :**

> [bool error (trying a game tutorial)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28013590/bool-error-trying-a-game-tutorial)

```
@IBAction func UIButtonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
    userMessage.hidden = true
    if plays[sender.tag] == nil && !aiDeciding && !done {
        setImageForSpot(sender.tag, player:1)
    }
```